# Is corneal ulcer contagious?

Tags: eye, ulcers, cornea

My father is suffering from corneal ulcer. So, I want to know if it is contagious. Materials on the net are not correct, and proposals in the same article (like [this](https://www.firmoo.com/answer/question/8265.html)) contradict each other. That's why I want an authentic answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple variables, let me explain.

An ulcer itself is not contagious. It is just an open sore that won't heal properly. What exactly causes an ulcer to occur needs to be determined by a physician. Contact lense wearers and individuals whom scratch the cornea are more susceptible to ulcers and bacterial issues. The short answer is no the ulcer is not contagious. HOWEVER if the ulcer is a result of bacterial infection it very well could be. Bacteria is non discriminatory, so you could possibly pick something up if you come into contact with any objects or non sterile material that someone else touches or has.

Rubbing eyes, or sharing contact lense solution could possibly transfer bacterium. Nothing is contagious as long as you take the proper medical precaution. It's best to practice very good hygiene.

Comment: Welcome to Health. While your answer is correct, it would be great if you could find some sources that support it.  Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*.